# Relation between two answered problem in Lebesuge Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

yesterday I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084166/if-f-is-lebesgue-integrable-then-for-every-epsilon0-there-is-a-set-e-of/1084193#1084193) and we get the answer, for reference this is what we ask

> Problem 1 : Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ is a real-valued function on $X$ such that $$\int_X |f| d\mu <\infty$$ . Then for any $\epsilon >0$ we can find a measurable set $E$ such that $\mu(E) <\infty$ and $$ \int_{X \backslash E} |f| d\mu <\epsilon.$$

There is another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870142/find-delta-0-such-that-int-e-f-d-mu-epsilon-whenever-mue-delta) which asked before,for reference this is the question :-

> Probelm 2 : Find $\delta >0$ such that $\int_E |f| d\mu < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E)<\delta$

My question: Is there is a way can go from the first problem to the second one? which we should directly use the first problem in proving the second one.

Comment: Problem 1 assumes $\int_X |f|<\infty$. That's not assumed in the linked question.

Comment: If you assume $f$ is integrable, consider the functions $f_n=\max\{|f|, n\}$. $(f_n)$ is a non-decreasing sequence with pointwise limit $|f|$. So $\int f_n$ converges to $\int |f|$. Note $\int_E |f|=\int_E (|f|-f_n)+\int_E f_n$ and that for a fixed $n$, $\int_E f_n$ is small if $\mu(E)$ is small enough.

Comment: So, no, the two problems are very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by David Mitra, the two problems are rather different. The first property states that $f$ is small enough, so that it takes small values on sets of infinite measure -  a rough analogy on $\Bbb R^n$ would be that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. In contrast, the second property says that the measure $\mathrm d\nu = f\;\mathrm d\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$ which of course uses the fact that $f$ is not incredibly big but in essence the issues here may arise even if $\int f\mathrm d\mu$ is finite. Yet again, roughly it means that the first property is violated if $f = \infty$ on positive $\mu$ sets, whereas the second is violated if $f = \infty$ on null $\mu$ sets.

That said, in math one can rarely really safely claim that two results are completely unrelated.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I know in math most of problem are can be related in some way, but in this problem I meant directly or heavily,but your answer give more insight about the two problem.